# How to update entity values to the object in a ArrayList while iterating and checking another ArrayList of Object

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

I am having a situation where I am iterating through an ArrayList of objects and adding the values of that ArrayList to another ArrayList based on the condition if they are empty or not .Now I want to update a value of a particular entity of the ArrayList where I am adding the values from another ArrayList. Let me post the code also and explain

This is the Destination entity where I am storing the values

```
public class DestDO{
private String id;
private String name;
private String phase;
private String attr;
private String isComplete;
```

This is the Source entity from where i am getting the values

```
public class SourceDO{
private String id;
private String name;
private String phase;
private String attr;
```

This is the class where i am setting the values

```
public class DataInjectService{

 public List<SourceDO> addAllValues(){

  List<SourceDO> addedListValues = Arrays.asList(

  new SourceDO("1","Jeet","KI","D"),
  new SourceDO("1","John","KA","E"),
  new SourceDO("1","HARRY","KU","R")
);
return addedListValues
```

This is the driver class

```
public class TestArrayList{
 public static void main(String a[]){
 DataInjectService dataInjectService = new DataInjectService ();
 List<SourceDO> listOfSourceObj = 
 System.out.println(mapSourceToDest(listofSourceObj);
}
```

In this operation if any of the sourceDO value is null then I have to set false to the isComplete entity else I sourceDO contains all values then I have to set true to the isComplete entity.To be more precise say sourceDO.getName() is empty then even if other values of sourceDO is non empty I have to set false to the isComplete entity. Is this possible ?

```
public static List<DestDO> mapSourceToDest(List<SourceDO> listOfSourceObj){
 List<DestDO> desiredResult = new ArrayList<>();
 for(SourceDO sourceDo : listOfSourceDO){
  desiredResult.add(DestDO.builder()
   .id(Optional.ofNullable(sourceDO.getId()).orElse(""))
   .name(Optional.ofNullable(sourceDO.getName()).orElse(""))
   .phase(Optional.ofNullable(sourceDO.getPhase()).orElse(""))
   .attr(Optional.ofNullable(sourceDO.getAttr()).orElse(""))
   .isComplete(// here i have to change the status
```

I am trying to do a Java 8 approach which can be fit in this operation , please help me if this is possible

Comment: Note: I would create a helper method `String emptyIfNull(String str) { return str != null ? str : ""; }` instead of using that tedious `Optional.ofNullable(...).orElse("")`

Comment: @MCEmperor can you please edit my code i have added the full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check your attributes, there are many ways, I would suggest to use:

```
private static boolean verifyAnyNull(SourceDO sourceDo) {
    return Arrays.asList(
            sourceDo.getId(),
            sourceDo.getName(),
            sourceDo.getPhase(),
            sourceDo.getAttr()
    ).contains(null);
}
```

and then call your method:

```
.isComplete(verifyAnyNull(sourceDo))
```

I assume that complete is a boolean and not String

Comment: isComplete can be a boolean, can i use some one liner approach ?

Comment: ok, then try this solution, as I said there are many ways to solve your issue

Comment: What did you mean *can i use some one liner approach*

Comment: meaning if i can decide from here only and at the end i update the isComplete values  desiredResult.add(DestDO.builder()
   .id(Optional.ofNullable(sourceDO.getId()).orElse(""))

Comment: @Mandrek You have to check your attributes to know if there are null or not, I'm not sure I get your question